# GAE Google App Engine Captcha for Java (no 3rd party)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, awt, captcha, recaptcha

I need a captcha solution for GAE in Java. My clients only have access to the IP in where my application is hosted so they can't rely on re-captcha or solutions of this kinds.

Since awt image classes are blocked. Do you know any easy solution for image generation ?

Comment: Ticket to include awt to GAE: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 've found a text-to-image library which works on GAE:
[Litetext](http://code.google.com/p/litetext/)

But it's not secure enough for a captcha.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own CAPTCHA images using the [Images API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview). Preload one or more image per alphabet character into the Blobstore, then use a combination of the available transformations. These include resize, rotate, flip, crop, and composite, which will get you pretty far. The result probably won't be very resistant to concerted automated attack, but is better than nothing.

Comment: This could work but it wouldn't be strong and I'm looking for something already done.